# USB to RS485: Can I connect A to Common Ground?

Tags: usb, ground, digital-communications, rs485

I bought a [very cheap USB to RS485 dongle](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32777508190.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dsNnvKa) to connect to an experimental board of my own.

Specifications (may differ from the one I used but externally similar):
- Any baud rate from 1200 bps to 115 kbps
- Current: 100mA current at 5V DC taken from PC’s USB Port
- Modes: RS-485 Half Duplex (2-wire)
- Built in terminal resistor of 120R Ohm
- The USB-RS485 cable is a USB to RS485 levels serial UART converter cable incorporating FTDI’s FT232RQ USB to serial UART interface IC device which handles all the USB signalling and protocols. The cable provides a fast, simple way to connect devices with a RS485 interface to USB.

- Any baud rate from 1200 bps to 115 kbps
- Current: 100mA current at 5V DC taken from PC’s USB Port
- Modes: RS-485 Half Duplex (2-wire)
- Built in terminal resistor of 120R Ohm
- Length of twisted pair cable maximum can be 1.2 Km (Kilometer) Maximum
- Cable type for optimal range: Two core, Twisted Pair Shielded type, D+ and D- (actualy A and B) should be twisted with each other to get optimal range

This dongle had only A and B outputs. No GND pin. My experimental board has its data input connected to the input of a schmitt trigger. In order to read the data with the schmitt trigger, I connected output B from the dongle to the schmitt trigger input (B line) and output A to the ground of my board.
Between the USB-to-RS485 B output and the schmitt trigger BUF1, there is a 470 ohms resistor R1, a schottky diode D1 from ground to the B lime, a 5V zener z1 between ground to the B line and a second resistor of 140 ohms R2. 
[image]

Bit "0" were at 3.2V and bit "1" at 0V. I added the schottky diode from ground to erase a very short negative voltage drop at each falling edge between a "0" and a "1". 
The 5V zener diode is just elementary protection (just in case). The resistors help reduce noise, albeit not totally and increase protection.
There is a lot of noise on the B line, but it worked perfectly. ...Until after a few test, the dongle started to heat and stop responding. The plastic cover even thermo-deformed.
I transfered very short data, at the default baud rate of 19200. It wasn't used intensively.

Now I'm using a [less cheap yet still quite cheap dongle](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32888122294.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dsNnvKa) which has a GND and a +5V pins on top of A and B.  It works very well too. 
But I'm afraid it will be destroyed in the same way if I did a mistake.

I didn't try connecting USB ground to common ground because the voltage difference would not fit for detecting data with the schmitt trigger. On ouptu B, Bit "0" is at 5V relative to the USB ground and bit "1" is at 2.5V relative to USB ground. On output A Bit "0" is at 0V and bit "1" at 2.5V.

My question is: Did the very cheap dongle melt because it was very cheap or because I did a mistake in the circuit?

Comment: Date sheet for the melted dongle. I mean a data sheet not some ebay or amazon link.

Comment: Two issues: 1st. the dongle does not provide GND beside that is not isolated. 2nd: you do need a RS485 transceiver, not a Schmidt trigger.

Comment: @Andy aka Nobody seems to have a datasheet pdf. I could only find these additional infos (see edited question)

Comment: IMO the best investment in the USB RS485 dongle is the one advertised as FT232 + ADM2587 on the same website. It's not as nearly cheap as proposed devices by you, but I guess it works and it can't burn the PC or MCU board.

Comment: Marko Buršič Maybe I should use a USB to TTL (lot of choice) but theorically I would need RS485 for long distances. I was thinking about using a RS485 transceiver on my board, and I would eventually do if it's necessary on some networks. But for a cheap version, not using a  RS485 transceiver make a big cost difference. I works perfectly (with both dongles), Just strange why the first dongle burned out.  I can't see what's wrong with my circuit.

Comment: The RS485 output is differential. Both A and B outputs will toggle, they should basically both be 3V or 5V complementary outputs in respect to PC chassis GND, and to prevent going out of the common mode range of RS485 chips, your other device must have same ground reference than PC ground. Using floating powersupplies or ungrounded outlet for PC is wrong if there is no separate ground reference wire. Grounding the A wire directly is not wise either.

Answer (score 2):

It was a mistake. By connecting the dongle GND to the common GND on my board, instead of output B, not only the strong noise completely disapeared (meaning something there was conflicting tension between A and B) but an indicator led on the dongle stopped shining.
Because they sell these things without any serious instruction, I didn't know this LED means there is something wrong with the network. I thought it was normal.

I'm very suprised that my experiment worked because I thought the difference between between 2.3V and 4V would not be interpreted correctly by the schmitt trigger, but it was. The good surprise was to see a short drop to near 0V, for about 2us. This drop allows the schmitt trigger to go low and it returns to high only after its imput crosses the high level treshold.

However the schmitt trigger's high level treshold (typ 2.4V at 4.5V Vcc)  is very close to the low state voltage of output A (2.3V) and could even be under if lower than typical or Vcc is less than 5V.
So it's not very reliable IMO. 
[image: new schematic]
This is the signal with the corrected circuit:
The yellow line is A output from the dongle.
The pink line is the signal after the schmitt trigger.
[image: capture]

Comment: The reason it made a difference is most likely because the ground was not disconnected. The dongle was trying to let current onto line B to try to raise it to a certain voltage, but no matter how much current it let out, the current just kept flowing back to ground along some path and the voltage stayed at 0.